# Is it possible to develop the ssh protocol in rebol?

Tags: rebol

Rebol integrates most internet protocol but not ssh. Is it because it's impossible to program it in rebol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's not impossible.  It's just a question of resources.  If you had the money spare, you could sponsor the addition of a SSH protocol by offering a bounty.  I think $10k should cover it.

Comment: Huh I'm already paying my mother's retirement so I'll need to keep the money :)

Comment: So SSH protocol is so hard to implement that's a pity !